# R Shiny JS jump to last page conflicting with auto generate value in new row

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a `Shiny` app that allows the user to enter their project details to the database. This is achieved by the `Add Project Details` Button that adds an empty row to the table. When the add button is clicked the app auto generates the next reference number (under column Reference.Number) in the new row based on the previous one.

Another function of the `Add` button is also to make the app jump to the last page of the table rather than having the user click on the last page number under the table.

The app almost works fine because when I click the `Add` button, the app does temporarily go the last page, but as soon as the auto generate value is calculated, the app goes back to the first page of the table.

What could be causing this conflict and how can this be fixed?

Sample data (`df`):

```
df <- structure(list(Reference.Number = c("33331", "33332", "33333", 
                                          "33334", "33335"), 
                     Request.Date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", 
                                                                              "1/20/2021", "1/24/2022"), 
                     Requestor.Name = c("Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Updated maps for David", "    Stone Cold", "Updated SOE 60 inch wall map"),
                     Requestor.Dept.Div = c("C 3 Staff",    "C 3 Staff", "Unincorp & Comm", "Mt.Rushmore AME Church Ft. Billy",                                         "SOE"), 
                     Requestor.Phone = c("", "", "", "", ""), 
                     Contact.Person = c("Tommy",                             "Tommy", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"),
                     Contact.Phone = c("1111",                               "2222", "3333", "ext 1111", "3434"),
                     Deadline = c("1/20/2022",         "1/20/2022", "1/22/2022", "", "1/24/2022"),
                     Project.Description = c("45x36 portrait map ",          "45x36 portrait map  ",   "24x24 Unincorporated areas", "Percent Females Aged 25 - 55  Below Poverty Level By Zip Code",                "SOE Wall Map 60x60 p"), 
                     Project.File.Location = c("", 
                                                  "", "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14785 Unincorporated 24x24.pdf", 
                                                  "C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel.aprx", 
                                                  "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14786 V P 60x60.pdf"
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application 
ui =   navbarPage(tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}"),
                  title = div("GIS Team Projects"),
                  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                  tabPanel("GIS Projects",
                           icon = icon("info"),
                           div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                           p("1. The user can add their project details.", style="color:black"),
                           uiOutput("all"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details"),
                      ),
                    mainPanel(
                      downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                      DTOutput("contents"),
                      tags$script(HTML("
           Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('messageJumpToLast', function(message) {
               // select the target table via its container ID and class:
               var target = $('#contents .dataTable');
               // display last page:
               target.dataTable().api().page('last').draw(false);
           });
           "))),
                    )
                    )
)

# Define server logic required 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  myData = reactiveVal(df)
  
  # Create an 'empty' tibble 
  user_table =  
    df %>% 
    slice(1) 
  
  user_table[1,]<-NA
  
  # Display data as is
  output$contents =
    renderDT(myData(),
             server = FALSE,
             editable = TRUE,
             options = list(lengthChange = TRUE),
             rownames = FALSE)
  
  # Store a proxy of contents 
  proxy = dataTableProxy(outputId = "contents")
  
  # Each time addData is pressed, add user_table to proxy
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$addData, {
    myData(myData() %>% bind_rows(user_table %>% 
  mutate(Reference.Number=as.character(max(as.numeric(myData()$Reference.Number), na.rm = T)+1))))
  session$sendCustomMessage('messageJumpToLast', 'some payload here, if needed') # Don't know if this should be added or not!
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stéphane Laurent deserves all credit for this. Essentially I just used the original posters code and updated it with the answer from Stéphane Laurent. There are certain things like the `observeEvent()` that don't work as originally posted without the user of the `addRow()`.  Anyways, this should work. Best of luck

```
df <- data.frame(structure(list(Reference.Number = c("33331", "33332", "33333", 
                                                     "33334", "33335"), 
                                Request.Date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", 
                                                 "1/20/2021", "1/24/2022"), 
                                Requestor.Name = c("Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Updated maps for David", "    Stone Cold", "Updated SOE 60 inch wall map"),
                                Requestor.Dept.Div = c("C 3 Staff",    "C 3 Staff", "Unincorp & Comm", "Mt.Rushmore AME Church Ft. Billy",                                         "SOE"), 
                                Requestor.Phone = c("", "", "", "", ""), 
                                Contact.Person = c("Tommy",                             "Tommy", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"),
                                Contact.Phone = c("1111",                               "2222", "3333", "ext 1111", "3434"),
                                Deadline = c("1/20/2022",         "1/20/2022", "1/22/2022", "", "1/24/2022"),
                                Project.Description = c("45x36 portrait map ",          "45x36 portrait map  ",   "24x24 Unincorporated areas", "Percent Females Aged 25 - 55  Below Poverty Level By Zip Code",                "SOE Wall Map 60x60 p"), 
                                Project.File.Location = c("", 
                                                          "", "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14785 Unincorporated 24x24.pdf", 
                                                          "C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel.aprx", 
                                                          "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14786 V P 60x60.pdf" 
                                ))))
#Made data into dataframe, slice for me doesn't work with the list


library(shiny)
# library(shinythemes #I don't think this is important to the question and I don't have shinythemes
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

callback <- c( # with this callback, the app does not jump to the last page if
  '$("#addData").on("click", function(){', # the added row goes to a new page
  '  table.page("last").draw("page");',
  '});'
)
callback <- c( # so we use this callback which includes a small delay (200ms)
  '$("#addData").on("click", function(){',
  '  setTimeout(function(){table.page("last").draw("page");}, 200);',
  '});'
)

# Define UI for application 
ui =   navbarPage(tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}"),
                  title = div("GIS Team Projects"),
                  # theme = shinytheme("cyborg"), #I don't think this is important to the question
                  tabPanel("GIS Projects",
                           icon = icon("info"),
                           div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                           p("1. The user can add their project details.", style="color:black"),
                           uiOutput("all"),
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details"),
                             ),
                             mainPanel(
                               downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                               DTOutput("contents"),
                               tags$script(HTML("
           Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('messageJumpToLast', function(message) {
               // select the target table via its container ID and class:
               var target = $('#contents .dataTable');
               // display last page:
               target.dataTable().api().page('last').draw(false);
           });
           "))
                             ),
                           )
                  )
)

# Define server logic required 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  myData = reactiveVal(df)
  
  # Create an 'empty' tibble 
  user_table =  
    df %>% 
    slice(1) 
  
  user_table[1,]<-NA
  
  # Display data as is
  output$contents =
    renderDT({
      datatable(isolate(myData()), #Isolate is needed for Stéphane Laurent's answer
                # server = FALSE, #Moved to below
                editable = TRUE,
                options = list(lengthChange = TRUE),
                rownames = FALSE,
                callback = JS(callback)
      )}, server = FALSE
    )
  
  # Store a proxy of contents 
  proxy = dataTableProxy(outputId = "contents")
  
  # Each time addData is pressed, add user_table to proxy
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$addData, {
    #Original way of adding data doesn't work with Stéphane Laurent's answer, so I updated using their format
    # myData(myData() %>% bind_rows(user_table %>% 
    #                                 mutate(Reference.Number=as.character(max(as.numeric(myData()$Reference.Number), na.rm = T)+1))))
    newRow<-user_table %>% #replaced the original info with the answer from Stéphane Laurent
      mutate(Reference.Number=as.character(max(as.numeric(as.character(myData()$Reference.Number)), na.rm = T)+1))
    myData(rbind(myData(), newRow)) # just to keep track of the changes
    addRow(proxy, newRow, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["contents_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["contents_edit"]]
    myData(editData(myData(), info, proxy))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try with your app because it gives me headache. Here is a minimal example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details", class = "btn-primary"),
  br(), br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12, 
      DTOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
)

callback <- c( # with this callback, the app does not jump to the last page if
  '$("#addData").on("click", function(){', # the added row goes to a new page
  '  table.page("last").draw("page");',
  '});'
)
callback <- c( # so we use this callback which includes a small delay (200ms)
  '$("#addData").on("click", function(){',
  '  setTimeout(function(){table.page("last").draw("page");}, 200);',
  '});'
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Dat <- reactiveVal(iris)
  
  #mytable
  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      isolate(Dat()),
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = list(target = "cell"),
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")
  
  #bind clicks
  observeEvent(input[["addData"]], {
    newRow <- data.frame(
      "Sepal.Length" = runif(1, 5, 7),
      "Sepal.Width"  = runif(1, 2, 4),
      "Petal.Length" = runif(1, 3, 5),
      "Petal.Width"  = runif(1, 0, 2),
      "Species"      = "setosa" 
    )
    Dat(rbind(Dat(), newRow)) # just to keep track of the changes
    addRow(proxy, newRow, resetPaging = FALSE)
  }) 
  
  # remove btn
  observeEvent(input[["mytable_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["mytable_edit"]]
    Dat(editData(Dat(), info, proxy))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: No worries, so what are the `runif`s doing?

Comment: I basically don't understand the `newRow` bit. An explaination of that will be appreciated.

Comment: So, I basically took the `callback` portion of your code and put it in my code and I am getting `Error in JS: object 'callback' not found`. Should I post the new `code` as an update in the question?

Comment: **runif** generates a number at random. The **callback** object is defined in my code, surely you didn't copy it.

Comment: Thank you, so maybe I am copying it at the wrong place in my code?

Comment: Hi Mr. Laurent, can you kindly modify your answer that incoporates `callback` in the code provided in the question?

Comment: Why? I don't see any problem.

Comment: Because just copying the `callback` portion of your code to mine doesn't work.

Comment: So maybe you can try it with my code, sorry about that and thank you.

Comment: If you get a **not found** error, then either you didn't copy the callback, or you copied it below the server, or you mispelled something.

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just that the app still stays on the first page of the table. Can we continue the discussion in chat? I wanted to send you the code to show what and where I copied `callback`.